# Which English word has the greatest number of distinct definitions?

Tags: homework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Words with most meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42480/words-with-most-meanings)

For example:

> #### [in·se·cure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insecure?s=t) [in-si-kyoor]
> <sup>*adjective*</sup>
>
> 1. subject to fears, doubts, etc.; not self-confident or assured: *an insecure person.*
> 2. not confident or certain; uneasy; anxious: *He was insecure about the examination.*
> 3. not secure; exposed or liable to risk, loss, or danger: *an insecure stock portfolio.*
> 4. not firmly or reliably placed or fastened: *an insecure ladder.*

We find the word *"insecure"* has four distinct definitions. Which English word has the greatest number of distinct definitions?