# Where does the phrase “run code” or “run software” come from? Why “run”?

Tags: etymology, verbs, programming, software

Historically speaking, it makes sense to me someone would say run "the computer". Early computers (not a human computer) were mechanical machines with moving parts that could achieve a velocity deemed "running" from the perspective of a human being. I don't know for sure if that is the reason why, but that seems plausible.

But why run the "program", "code" or "software"?

Comment: This might not be answerable definitively, as jargon is rarely documented; and lacking documentation, "to run" meaning "to make a thing go" is so common in English that it would be unusual for the word use for code to *not* be "run". It might be akin to asking "Where does the phrase 'walk the dog' come from? Why 'walk'?" The answer may merely be "Because that's what the word means."

Comment: It's a difficult question, no doubt. I'm hoping someone would either have lived long enough to have a story to tell from the past that sheds light on why. Or someone would make an argument that I find convincing.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22run+a+program%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22run+a+program%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SVxLUKT6IKet0QXghYCIAg&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A23%2F5%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A23%2F5%2F1925&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3b003db65f44374e&biw=1379&bih=886) are a couple of instances of **run a program** from 1924. The usage long predates computers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "run" in conjunction with "program" is shedding a light that makes a lot of sense to me. It's like a director requesting that actors act out what is on the script/program/code. A programmer requests that the computer act out what is on the script/program/code.

Comment: Whatever makes sense to you. It's pretty obvious from the answers here that different people have wildly differing rationalisations for why "run" is used in this sense. But as @Hugo points out, it's now the word with the most meanings in the *Oxford English Dictionary*. This is just one of them, which relates more closely to some alternative meanings than it does to others. Note that the OED entry starts with *"**run**: a verb of complicated history in Eng."* You've picked a really awkward word if you're looking for simple explanations!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems to have been a natural extension of the usage of "run" which is used as a synonym for *to operate* or *to cause to operate*.  An example being "The engine is running."

If I had to speculate, *that* particular meaning could have come from the speedy motion one can observe, for instance, seeing an engine operating. This is pure conjecture, however, since there are also *other* correct usages of the word run which are entirely procedural in nature, e.g. "To run a business."

Comment: Run the "computer" makes sense to me in that regards, it's using the "machine" metaphor. But why run "code"? It's just a pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the origin, but normally, code is considered "steps" to be executed. In debugger you can "step forward" one instruction ahead. If you let the computer execute the steps as fast as it only can, it's called "run".

Comment: In my mind, a machine is normally just running an "instruction loop" an engineer "programmed" using physics, the only difference is the level of abstraction. When a computer is "running" it's either processing instructions or waiting for instructions to process.  When you give it new instructions, it "runs" those.

Comment: @mootinator: The idea of the computer "waiting" for instructions is really just metaphorical - usually it's just repeatedly executing the low-level instructions involved in checking to see it there's anything else it should be doing. But a modern machine will reduce its execution speed to save energy/reduce heat if it doesn't keep finding plenty to do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. My point was that a computer isn't doing anything significantly different when it "runs a program" as opposed to when it is simply "running".

Comment: "run" was also well established both as a verb in the sense of "run its course" and as a corresponding noun meaning "series of consequences" (e.g. "He had a run of bad luck"). So it may also be a natural extension of this specific meaning.

Answer (score 16):

**Where does the phrase “run code” or “run software” come from? Why “run”?**

### *Run*

As detailed in another [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/42551/9001), *run* is now the word with the most meanings in the *Oxford English Dictionary*. From the *[New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/29/opinion/29winchester.html?_r=1)*:

> It took Peter Gilliver, the O.E.D. lexicographer working on the letter R, more than nine months harnessed to the duties of what Samuel Johnson once called “a harmless drudge” (plus many more months of preparatory research) to work out what he believes are all the meanings of “run.” And though some of the senses and their derivations try him — Why does a dressmaker run up a frock? Why run through a varlet with a sword? How come you run a fence around a field? Why, indeed, run this essay? — Mr. Gilliver has finally calculated that there are for the verb-form alone of “run” no fewer than 645 meanings. A record.

As *run* is so versatile, it comes as no surprise that it was applied to computers and computer programs from the earliest days of computers.

An earlier related meaning in the *OED* is the verb to keep or operate machinery, for example from 1840:

> The farmers would find it difficult to run a mill to make cloths, or to build and sail a ship to take his produce to market.

And the noun, the act of making machinery run from 1864:

> The Blue Gravel claim (placer) at Smartsville, cleared up, after a run of two weeks of their mill, the sum of $44000.

The first electronic digital computers were developed between 1940 and 1945 and it's not surprising the earliest relevant *OED* entry for the noun *run* is from 1941.

> **IV.** Senses relating to the operation or management of something.
>
> **IV 50 d.** *Computing.* An instance of the execution of a program or other task by a computer.
>
> 1941   Jrnl. Amer. Statist. Assoc. 36 513   While a maximum of 54 runs through the tabulator is required, only one-ninth of the cards are used during each run.

The verb follows from this:

> **V.** To (cause to) operate or function.
>
> **79. d.** (a) *trans. Computing.* To perform (a computation) on a computer; to cause the instruction in (a program) to be carried out, to execute. Cf. run *n.2* 50d.
>
> 1946   *Man. Operation Automatic Sequence Controlled Calculator* (Harvard Computation Lab.) vi. 289   A clear copy of the coding must be provided before an attempt is made to run a sequence tape on the calculator.

### *Code*

Modern computer programs are software written with a programming language, and software can be run on a computer. A program is a special code that a computer process and can understand, and software is also known as a code. (Writing a program is also known as coding.) Early programs were "written" by punching holes in tape in a special sequence, or code, that the computer could process and execute, or run.

This meaning of code also comes from the early days of computing. The *OED*:

> **3. c.** *Cybernetics.* Any system of symbols and rules for expressing information or instructions in a form usable by a computer or other machine for processing or transmitting information.
>
> 1946   *Nature* 26 Oct. 568/1   The brains of the machine lie in the control tape, which is code-punched in three sections.

Comment: I suspect this was only a record because Mr. Peter Gilliver was not working on the letter `F`...

Comment: From the same NYT article: In terms of sheer size, the entry for “run” is half as
big again as that for “put,” a word on which Mr.
Gilliver also worked some years ago. But more
significantly still, “run” is also far bigger than the
old chestnut “set,” a word that, says Mr. Gilliver,
simply “hasn’t undergone as much development in the 20th and 21st centuries as has ‘run.’ ”

Comment: Yes, but how does it compare to the universal adjective? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NvDZpICdzo

Answer (score 5):

The first general purpose computers were [large machines](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/eniac.html). They did not execute the typical stored instruction programs that we have today.  Each instruction had to be wired by hand by connecting terminals on plugboards with one or more patch cables.  This sometimes took days to complete and verify.  Once the program was "wired", the machine could be turned on and allowed to ***run***.

> [***run***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/run?region=us&q=run) : *7 be in or cause to be in operation; function or cause to function*
>
> [*etymology*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=run&searchmode=none): of machinery, from 1560s.

From [*The ENIAC Story*](http://ftp.arl.mil/~mike/comphist/eniac-story.html):

> Coders, programmers, and engineers made ***it run*** and produced useful results which otherwise would have been unattainable. The rapid progress of computer technology, spurred by the ENIAC itself ...

Comment: They might be smaller, but modern microprocessor-based systems are still "wired", "turned on", etc. Functionally, they pretty much do the same as ever - they execute (or run, if you like) code.

Comment: The point is that they were  machines and the typical terminology for machines was "to run". Nowadays, a computer is "running" pretty much all the time and while the computer is running, programs are loaded and executed, whereas back then the machines were "programmed" with the machine off and then set to run.  Thus "running" a program.

Comment: I disagree with the entire association of running code with running machinery in that mechanical sense. It's the *sequence of instructions* which are being run (stepped through), not the processor "running" (operational, turned on, doing work, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, this is plausible. However, without a cite, it's as much speculation as the rest of the answers.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I don't see how any amount of citations could make this line credible to me. Here's [run a business](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+a+good+principle+on+which+to+run+a+business%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in 1803 - are we going to say *that* derives from an allusion to machinery being turned on and doing work?

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, but it's entirely possible for "run a business" to have a common ancestor with "run machinery" *and* for "run a program" to derive from analogy to machinery. There's no contradiction there. Jim has the history of computer operation right, and it's not uncommon for words or phrases to undergo semantic broadening—it could have originally meant to operate the *machine* and then drifted over to "execute instructions step-by-step". Without a cite, though, it's all speculation. It's not heresy though!

Comment: @Jim: So you're saying that they used to say "run the program" back then instead of saying "run the machine", because the machine and the program were really one and the same thing? Is that an accurate understanding of what you mean?

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: Back when? All I'm saying is *running* has a lot of associations beyond "machinery in an operational state". The concept of "running" code only relates to machinery in the sense that we use hardware to execute software. Without the tin, we can only "single-step" the code as human beings (which is a lot slower than running it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Back when?" as in the time period when the term was plausibly coined.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Exactly. At that point in computer development it was the machine that was "run".  The machine did not really have a processor that fetched, decoded, and executed instructions like they do today.

Answer (score 4):

It's a normal [metaphor for computing](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4compute.html). If you think about it, ***all*** computing terms are [bound to be metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf), since it's too new a phenomenon to have established terms.

And *Running Fast* is one of the most common. Running is something people and other animals do; it's an extension of the body, like [almost all metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf). And it's something that some are better at than others. Speed is part of that, but we also speak of Running Light or Running Well.

Comment: I understand that it's a metaphor, but I'm trying to find out why that metaphor. Running the "computer" makes sense to me as using the metaphor of a machine or an engine with moving parts that can achieve a certain velocity. I just don't understand why "code" (which is just a pattern) would be associated with "run"

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: You're conflating different computer senses of "code" - what gets "run" is *instruction codes* (increment this value, get a data value from this address, etc.). You (or more accurately, the computer, on your behalf) run/operate/execute those instructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh, I see... What you mean by code is the instructions, what I mean by the code is the pattern stored in memory or disk, more akin to the holes in the punchcard. That's what I've always thought "code" in "running code" meant. But you're saying that's not the case. Is that an accurate understanding of what you mean?

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: *Code=pattern* isn't a useful interpretation in this context. Think of it as *code=symbol*, where each "instruction" has a "symbolic representation". An individual instruction is normally **executed**, whereas a *sequence (run)* of instructions is normally **run**. But as John says, computing is too new for usage to be totally fixed - you can certainly *execute a series of instructions*, and many people would say you can *run a single instruction*.

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: Read _Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid._ It will make the distinction clear.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Does one really have to read GEB just to understand the difference between patterns stored in a medium VS pre-existing hardware instructions that has a "label"? Or are you referring to something specific in the book that cannot be found elsewhere?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So your saying that when people say "run code" they're referring not to the code they wrote, but to the machine code that already exists as part of the machine? Which is essentially part of the "machine", so the metaphor often used in relationship to a machine makes sense? Then if people think "code" in the context of "running code" refers to the code they wrote, they're just using it "wrong"?

Comment: Or else they're making a new metaphor. Metaphor is fluid, which is why metaphors flowed in naturally to fill the lexical vacuum around computing. And there are many different kinds of things that _can be run_ (the metaphor uses transitive causative _run_);  you can run machine code, you can run an algorithm or a subroutine or pseudo-code by making it into machine code, you can run a Unix command by hitting RETURN; you can run the numbers, run the data, run the billing procedures, run the audit or the auditing or the auditing software. It's a very versatile metaphor theme.

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: I think you're asking for more precision than actually exists here. Only programmers "run code", and they know perfectly well what they mean by the phrase. They also know what they mean by [dry-run the code](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dry+run+the+code%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which doesn't involve any machinery at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hm... Yeah, I was hoping this would be a simple question that brings up a historical story, but it doesn't seem so... As a phrase, maybe it could just as well mean "try it out" or "act out the script"

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: More accurately, **execute** the instructions (using the machine), or **cause the machine to be controlled (run)** by the code/program/script.

Answer (score 3):

From [New monthly magazine: Volume 21 (1827)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BCkAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=%22just%20run%20through%20it%22&source=bl&ots=pm0jia5gT9&sig=SRf1ZtiJ-3bB01MfBXovuT3dtAA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4Z1KUM3rL6mj0QWL34HgDg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22just%20run%20through%20it%22&f=false)

> we will just run through it, and glance at its most successful points.

where I read "run" as equivalent to "step quickly through". That's what computers have always done - stepping ever more quickly through ever more complex instruction sequences. There's also of course the long-standing sense of *running a business* (*executing* the procedures that businesses concern themselves with).

Programmers working at the detailed level *run code* (simple sequences being tested), and geeks *run software*. Everyone else *uses/starts a program* - or more likely an *app* nowadays.

Comment: computers running through or stepping through code or programmers running punch cards through the computer make sense to me. So I guess then the word "through" somehow disappeared?

Comment: @Seung Chan Lim: Let me run this one by you again. I could run you off (or up) a whole slew of different metaphorical uses of the word "run" - certainly enough to give you a run for your money. Many if not most of the metaphorical ways we use "run" have little or no direct connection to physical movement. Even if you run your business into the ground, it won't actually *go* anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

One of the earliest predecessors of the programmable computer was a programmable weaving machine, the [Jacquard loom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_loom). It used selected and changeable punch cards to program its output.

A next step, designed but not fully implemented, was also a mechanical programmable device, the [Analytic Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine) designed by Charles Babbage.
It was designed to use punch cards that activated physical wheels.

The [IBM punch card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card), which was the input media for both data and portions of the programs, is a direct decendant of these machines.  You only have to watch a punch card sorter or input reader flipping through a stack of cards and digesting the data to appreciate the aptness of **running code**.

Comment: So "running" code as in running cards through the machine? As in the cards are physically traveling into the machine at high speed?

Comment: @SeungChanLim They did. The sorting machine was a pre-computer device to sort by a given variable. The cards ran on rollers over bins and lights shone through holes that tripped levers to drop them in bins. Sorted cards were then assembled into a stack that was, in effect, the program. When cards were fed into the computer, the cards were put in a bin fed, through on rollers again over lights to "read" the holes in the cards and spit out into another bin. The data collected from this **run** was then processed a bit less physically.

Comment: The allusion to movement of card or paper tape is largely irrelevant. I started in programming using both those - I can assure you they only move when the program code is being **loaded** into the machine's memory. That happens **before** the code is "run". And the "running" might be delayed until you pressed a button - or typed "run", on later machines with actual keyboards.

Comment: I do not disagree with the various other analyses as to **run** meaning *operate* or *execute*. I just think that the early incarnations are in keeping with the metaphoric connotations.

Comment: @bib: Did people who used machines that read punch cards also say "run code"?

Comment: @bib- But they didn't start using *run* when they introduced the card reader, it was in use before that innovation.

Comment: ... yes bib, also I have often heard "running love"!

Comment: @Jim *running code* and *running software* was apparently used as early as about 1900 and came into vogue around the 1940s. See [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+code%2Crunning+code%2Crunning+software&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0).

Comment: @bib- If you look into those "apparent" usages you will find that they are not apropos.

Comment: @Jim How do I access them?