# What word in the English language has the most independently derived homonyms?

Tags: homonyms

I learned about yet another meaning for the word mode (and modal) today, and wondered, not for the first time, if there is any word in the English dictionary with more completely distinct meanings than mode, and with just one spelling. So this is my question:

Excluding heterograph homophones (only including exactly one spelling of a word), and including only distinct derivations (see the comments about beam below), what word has the greatest number of  distinct meanings?

Comment: One problem with even trying to find one, is just where does one draw the line between words and senses. Would you count *beam* meaning timber and *beam* meaning smile as separate words (and hence homonyms) or the same word (they're both from the same source after all, albeit a few steps of figurative use away from each other) and therefore not homonyms?

Comment: It depends somewhat on exactly who the speaker is. As an *exceptionally* "lazy" speaker, my renditions of *full, four, fall, fool* (and several other words) can sometimes be to all intents and purposes indistinguishable.

Comment: @Jon: I suppose one option would be to count *every* sense as distinct, but I'm not sure if that's what OP actually wants.

Comment: The intent of my question was to include distinct denotations for one spelling. The homophones FumbleFingers references have nothing to do with my question, and neither do the senses which are counted in the question Andrew Leach referenced. However, the word beam, as @JonHanna points out, is a good example of how arbitrary the line we draw can be, because I would definitely think of those as separate denotations, but the point at which I would consider two usages to be the same denotation is probably somewhat arbitrary. The space is so fluid, that it's hard to truly count distinctions.

Comment: Including related meanings probably makes this impractical to answer. I think it would be most interesting to focus on meanings that have independent derivations.

Comment: OK. Deal. I'm changing the question to clarify that we are only counting independent derivations.

Comment: I'm with @AndrewLeach here. It would be hard to distinguish the difference between the OP: *what word has the greatest number of distinct meanings?* and *[Word with most meanings](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42480/words-with-most-meanings)* versus whatever independent derivations is supposed to define.

Comment: Also [Are homonyms considered single words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123851/are-homonyms-considered-single-words?rq=1) and other related links would be of interest.

Comment: I don't know whether these count in this listing, but these words are all pronounced the same in English: air (atmosphere), aire (an old word for a tune), eyre (a legal term), ayre (another old word for a tune, or a sandbank), ere (before), heir (legatee), are (metric unit of area), and err (a variant pronunciation of err /er/, commit an error).  That's eight.

Comment: @tautophile - Very interesting example, though these would be homo*phones* - words that sound the same despite different spellings. Homonyms have the same spelling.